# How to center <ul> with margin attribute

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the `<ul>` to the middle of the page.  To do so, I am using the margin: 0 auto; attribute.  However, it isn't working.   Any ideas?

HTML

```
<body>

<header id="navHead">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="navLinks">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Me</li>
            <li>Assignments</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#navLinks {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#nav li {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#navHead {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: red;

}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5446w10/)

Comment: By "center the to the middle of the page", do you mean center the `<ul>` with id `"navLinks"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ul` is changed to an inline element, it doesn't respect the margin value `auto`. You *could* make it a block level element, and set a width on it, but that wouldn't work for content of dynamically varying widths.

In your case, just add `text-align:center` to the parent element. It works because the `ul` is inline.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p30t8qnn/)

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also change the display of the parent element to `table`. In doing so, `margin:auto` will work. Just make the children `li` elements `inline-block`.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5boegbu/)

```
#navLinks {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#nav li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

It's also worth noting that a `ul` has a default `padding-right` of ~`40px` in most browsers - remove that if you want it perfectly centered.

Also, since you are giving each `li` a `margin-right` of `20px`, the list isn't perfectly centered. Remove the margin from the last child.

```
#nav li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: UL is _not_ an inline element in any browser’s default stylesheet – it’s `block`.

Comment: @CBroe I never said it was by default. It is explicitly set to `inline-flex`.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/nwonwajL/2/)**

You can use following code in css file. You can minor changed in css for give `div` `text-align:center` and your `div` set center of header section. And your work has been complete.

CSS Code:

```
   #nav
{
    text-align:center;
    width : 100%;
}

#navLinks {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#nav li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline;
}


#navHead {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: red;

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<header id="navHead">
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navLinks">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
        <li>Assignments</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Results]